# Spring factory pattern

Tags: spring

Factory pattern is used to create objects runtime which provides loose coupling by placing object creation at one placce.Does Spring applies same pattern sincein spring we does coding to interface and keeps objects creation in xml configuration file?...

Comment: Yes it does (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spring allows it, by using `FactoryBean` interface. For more information follow these links:

- [What's a FactoryBean?](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)
- [Beyond the FactoryBean](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/10/beyond-the-factorybean/)
- [Spring Framework- Introducing Bean and Bean’s life(BeanFactory)](http://navin-bansal.blogspot.nl/2012/05/spring-framework-introducing-bean-and.html)